# Aspx pages will not load after upgrading from Asp.net MVC 2 to 3 RC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I upgraded to Asp.net MVC 3 RC last night and I followed the instructions on the release notes.  However, normal Aspx pages no longer work.

For example, when I go to the root (Home/Index), the following error occurs:

```
The view at '~/Views/Home/Index.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.
```

This is using a barely modified version of the original MVC Home/Index view.  The code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>
    <p>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Project List", "List", "Project", new { area = "writing" }, null) %>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

It is setup to inherit from ViewPage, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

The master page is unmodified from what MVC installs.

Any ideas?

Comment: i also upgraded last night, had no problems. take a look at this thread: http://forums.asp.net/p/1593209/4041505.aspx (maybe one of those solutions will work for you). Can you show your Controller code where your rendering the View? (unless its the default one, then don't worry)

Comment: It's the default home controller code.  All code I have written (except for the link in the view) resides in my own areas.  I'll check out that link though.

Comment: Nope nothing from that link worked :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

make sure you web.config has

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="WebMatrix.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
```

and this

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

as well as in any Areas/Web.config

Update them as needed and you should get to a better place

Comment: What`s the heirarchy that the `<assemblies>` node goes in?  (e.g. System.Web, controls, etc...)

Comment: Not sure what the core of the issue is, but I reverted back and re-attempted my update, and now everything is working good.  I'm marking this as the answer because those configs are good to know!

Comment: Thanks KallDrexx!  Yeah creating a new mvc project is the easiest way to do it but I had a fairly large project I didn't want to do the copy paste shuffle on.