# Asp.Net Mvc2 .ascx template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Why Asp.Net Mvc2 does not work? I get following error:

```
The view at '~/Views/Shared/Banner.ascx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TViewData>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TViewData>.
```

Comment: can you post your Banner.ascx code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banner.ascx isn't inherited from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl or ViewUserControl. as mentioned in error.

But it is too stupid to be true. Looks like you have the conflict of frameworks loaded in one application. Check next answers for the solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472040/182344
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169131/182344